What is the "intrinsic reason" for the failure of Schwarzschild coordinates in general relativity?
It is well known that the Schwarzschild metric fails at r = 2M (in units where c = G = 1) and this is the result of choosing "bad" coordinates. I find this surprising because the coordinates are not chosen "at random" in any sense.
On the contrary, it is known that the Schwarzschild solution is, in some sense, the unique solution of Einstein's equations which is both static and spherically symmetric. Now, both the latter conditions are intrinsic properties that can be expressed in terms of setting up various vector fields on the spacetime manifold.
So, it seems to me that the failure of Schwarzschild coordinates should correspond to a more "intrinsic" result, such as: "It is impossible to set up global vector fields with such and such properties on a Ricci-flat four dimensional manifold." Are there indeed any such results ?
Alternatively, there is no such result, but at some point in the derivation, we make a "bad choice" for coordinate parameters. I am not clear on where that happens - could someone point that out explicitly ?
Many thanks.

Have you read any of the standard investigations of your question, for example: https://www.people.vcu.edu/~rgowdy/phys691/pdf/holes.pdf

@RyanBudney that would make a reasonable answer, with some expansion. To non-experts, it might not be easy to find such references (grey literature like pdfs of lecture notes being even more subtle to find, sometimes).

Keyword: Killing horizon. The Schwarzschild coordinates are chosen such that the metric is diagonal and $\partial/\partial t$ is equal to the timelike Killing vector field. These requirements are incompatible at the horizon, which is where the Killing vector field becomes null, hence the coordinate singularity.

@Igor, could you please expand on your answer a bit ? I looked at the paper Ryan suggested, but it seems to be doing this same trial and error approach of "randomly changing coordinates until something works". Your answer seems more like what I was looking for.

@Anindya Sounds like you are now asking a different question. You should update your original post to make the updated question precise. But if your question is actually "why does the Schwarzschild solution continue past the horizon?" it is addressed in any textbook treatment.
